# Kobuki Not Moving on Navigation - move_base issue

Tags: navigation, move-base, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

My set up is Kobuki with s/w on Raspberry Pi with RPLIDAR A2 and that feeding back to a laptop. I'm trying to get the amcl_demo to work:

```
 roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/home/mark/KitchenMap.map.yaml --screen
```

The amcl seems to start without issue and reports:

```
[ INFO] [1489096786.597987673]: Got new plan
```

Eventually giving up with:

```
[ WARN] [1489096805.398058019]: Rotate recovery behavior started.
```

Which is when I would expect at lease *something* to happen. But the robot just stays still.

On the Pi side I see messages like:

```
[ WARN] [1489097005.894847319]: Velocity Smoother : using robot velocity feedback end commands instead of last command: 0.0349276, 0, -0.3, [navigation_velocity_smoother]
```

So something is not quite night. The only thing roswtf reports is:

```
Found 1 error(s).

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /move_base->/move_base (/move_base/global_costmap/footprint)
 * /move_base->/move_base (/move_base/local_costmap/footprint)
```

Which I don't think is much of an issue.

My rosgraph looks like this:

[rosgraph.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14890985687706006.png)

Any ideas what I've got missing or why this is happening?

Many Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256633/kobuki-not-moving-on-navigation---move_base-issue/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this to be a topic remapping issue. Once remapped all was well.

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2017-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0